# Error when trying to convert Java object to JSON string using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have an object MobilePhone with fields (String brand and name, int ram and rom) that I want to convert to a Json string. I try doing so like this

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone();
    mp.setBrand("iPhone");
    mp.setName("X");
    mp.setRam(4);
    mp.setRom(1);
    
    Gson json = new Gson();
    String object = json.toJson(mp);
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

I get the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public (package name).MobilePhone() accessible: module (project name) does not "exports (package name)" to module gson
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:349)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:289)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:189)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:182)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.newDefaultConstructor(ConstructorConstructor.java:101)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor.get(ConstructorConstructor.java:83)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
> at gson@2.8.2/com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
> at IAssessment/application.AddData.main(AddData.java:23) - this is line String object = json.toJson(mp);

Pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, the module containing the `MobilePhone` class does not export the package containing `MobilePhone`, so it is not visible outside of its own module. (Or if it is exported, it is only exported to some modules other than gson.) In general this means that you must add an `exports` directive to the module descriptor file, like so:

```java
exports <pkg-name> to gson;
```

But since gson uses reflection extensively, probably you need to go a step further and provide private and reflective access of the package to gson. To do this, add an `opens` directive to the module descriptor file:

```java
opens <pkg-name> to gson;
```

Comment: How do I open the module descriptor file? I'm not sure what that is. Sorry for the basic and or dumb questions, I'm quite t he novice in java and I am just now learning software development

Comment: Start with a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html) or check out the [Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) page.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. You're the 

Comment: Fantastic. It works!